# Is it possible to reload a UIWebView while the iOS app is backgrounded?

Tags: ios, background, uiwebview

Currently, I am loading an embedded music player inside of a UIWebView which works great. I also can reload the UIWebView with a new embedded player (when I want to play the next queued song for the user).. for the most part, with some slight issues.

It seems that when I am on Wi-Fi with stable bandwidth, all is well, the next song will load its embedded player in the UIWebView and begin playing.. but here's the catch.. when I am using data from my cellular provider with a variating cell service and have less than 2-3 bars of cell service, the UIWebView will not always reload in the background and play..

Any thoughts? I have tried using WKWebView which was even worse, along with forcing a "dummy" user action to attempt the UIWebView to play its content to no avail. I've also tried to set a timer that executes and attempts to force a reload if the embedded player is not playing the song, which doesn't seem to execute when the UIWebView doesn't load.. It's almost like I'm randomly entering an infinite loop when it doesn't load

Comment: have you registered your app to play background audio?

Comment: yes, it is registered, I am creating a javascript bridge between JS and Obj-C to monitor the state of the embedded music player through observers I add to the WebView on the Obj-C side of things. I consistently reach observer functions for when the next song loads and begins playback, but only occasionally (over a slower/intermittent connection) will the function that executes the "begins playback" state not actually begin playback..